# Разворачивание и сворачивание формы jQuery

Tags: jquery

Добрый день. Хочу сделать так, чтобы форма при нажатии на div разворачивалась, а при повторном нажатии - сворачивалась. Моя проблема: разворачивание происходит, но при повторном нажатии форма не сворачивается. Вот моя разметка HTML:

```
<div class="f">ответить
    <div class="answer">
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :text, 'Ваш ответ' %>
        <%= f.text_field :text, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>

      <%= f.submit 'Ответить', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Код jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".answer").hide();

    $(".f").click(function() {
        if ($(".answer", this.p == false)) {
            $(".answer", this).slideDown();
            $(".answer", this.p = true);
        }
        else {
            $(".answer", this).slideUp();
            $(".answer", this.p = false);
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: `<%= f.label :text, 'Ваш ответ' %>` - не html

что  вы пытаетесь добиться структурой

    ($(".answer", this.p == false)) 

?

Comment: @eicto, если происходит клик по div'у f, то его дочерний элемент разворачивается, и этому элементу присваивается true, чтобы потом определить развернут этот элемент или нет. Я думаю код очень очевидный. html.erb переводится при компиляции в чистый html код, не в нем дело, а в коде jQuery.

Comment: @Tkas конструкции 

    $(".answer", this.p == false)
    $(".answer", this.p = true);

непонятно что обозначают и что они передают для второго аргумента функции $. Первый передает вообще boolean, а второй всегда true (и его же присваивает свойству p полученного контекста)

Comment: @lampa как я задумывал изначально: когда мы нажимаем на .f и у его дочернего элемента некая переменная равно лжи, то происходит разворачивание и этой переменной устанавливается истина, чтобы при повторном нажатии определить свернут этот дочерний элемент или нет. Если при повторном нажатии дочерний элемент равен истине, то происходит сворачивание и этому элементу присваивается ложь, чтобы потом мы могли его развернуть. Вот такая вот неудачная задумка.

Comment: @Tkas ну я так и думал. Подскажу конечно. У jQuery есть метод [data()][1] в котором можно хранить всё, что угодно. 

    $(".f").click(function() {
        if($(this).data('open') != false) {
            $(this).data('open', false);
            $(".answer", this).hide();
        }
        else {
            $(this).data('open', true);
            $(".answer", this).show();
        }
    });


  [1]: http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: @lampa о, спасибо! Не знал о таком.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может так?

```
$(".f").click(function() {
   $(".answer", this).toggle();
});
```

Пример: http://jsfiddle.net/tkQMq/

P.S> Единственно что, скорее всего **.answer** нужнобудет вынести за пределы **.f**, тк если там форма то при клике она свернётся, тк **.answer** входит в "область клика" (читай в **.f**)

Comment: Правильней будет искать `.answer` в родителе, как хочет этого ТС :) См как работает второй аргумент функции `$`

А чтобы элемент не свернулся надо проверять действительно клик был по элементу `.f`

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду $(this).children('.answer').toggle(); ?

Comment: @Олег Б или вот так: $(".answer", this)

Comment: @lampla, для моего образования и для решения вопроса ТС, не могли бы вы продемонстрировать верный код, по вашему мнению?

Comment: @Олег Б у вас всё верно. По идее вот окончательный результат (ваш ответ будет применять метод toggle ко всем .answer найденным на странице)

    $(".f").click(function() {
        //$(this).children('.answer').toggle();
        $(".answer", this).toggle();
    });

Comment: Я имел ввиду: >> А чтобы элемент не свернулся надо проверять действительно клик был по элементу .f

Comment: @Олег Б проверять класс элемента, по которому кликнули, как вариант

Либо же добавить проверку по элементу: 

    $(".f").click(function(e) {
        if(e.target == this) {
             $(".answer", this).toggle();
        }
    });

Comment: @Олег Б спасибо вам за помощь, так действительно работает!

Comment: @lampa невнимательно просмотрел ваш ответ. Действительно, нужно узнать класс элемента по которому произошел клик, ибо если это не сделать, то при нажатии курсором на форму (чтобы ввести текст в нее) форма свернется, не смотря на то, что нажимали мы на другой div. Спасибо за уточненный код!!

Answer (score 1):

css: .f{display:none}

jquery: $('.f').click(function(){
        $(this).animate({"height": "toggle"});
})