# Сворачивание элементов по клику jQuery

Tags: jquery, ul, toggle

Есть простой список

```html
<ol id="commentlist">
    <li class="comment byuser">
        Comment 1
        <ul class="children">
            <li>Subcomment 1.1</li>
            <li>Subcomment 1.2</li>
            <li>Subcomment 1.3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="comment byuser">
        Comment 2
        <ul class="children">
            <li>Subcomment 2.1</li>
            <li>Subcomment 2.2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ol>
```

И код, который добавляет ссылку "Еще комментарии" если внутри li есть .children.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.comment .children').parent('.comment')
      .after('<a rel="nofollow" class="toggleCom" href="#" class="comment-reply-link">Еще комментарии</a>');
   //По клику на любую ссылку раскрываются все .children, а необходимо только для конкретной кнопки
   $(".toggleCom").on("click", function(e){
      $(".children").slideToggle();
   });

});
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать чтобы по клику на ссылку скрывался и раскрывался список .children?

Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Разворачивание и сворачивание формы jQuery](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/264384/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%8b-jquery)

Comment: добавил в onclick  $(".children", this).toggle(); - не работает

Comment: $(this).find('.children').toggle()

Comment: $(this).find('.children').toggle()  - не работает. Класс children не находится внутри  этой ссылки, он находится вместе со ссылкой в классе comment

Answer (score 0):

Блин, пока вам объяснял - сам решил как это сделать)) Вот ответ

$(".toggleCom").on("click", function(e){
  $(this).parent('.comment').find('.children').slideToggle();
});